Capturing IPs to run subsequent jobs in GitHub Actions using a matrix job strategy
I am working on developing a deployment workflow via GH actions for Azure.  I have worked out the outputs:, how to capture the IPs of the new deployed vms, and the job strategy for the subsequent jobs.
outputs:
        ip-addresses: ${{ steps.get-ips.outputs.ips }}

run: |
    $ips = @() 
    foreach ($i in ${{ github.event.inputs.vmcount }}) { 
      $ip=(Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName my-rg).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress 
      $ips += $ip 
    } 
    $json = $ips | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray -Compress 
    Write-Output $json 
    echo "ips=$json" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT

- name: Output values
  run: |
    echo ${{ steps.get-ips.outputs.ips }}

This works well but I am capturing all IPs from the specified resource group.  If there are additional vms besides the newly deployed ones, those IPs will also be captured.  I just want the IPs of the newly deployed vms if there happens to be others present.
Any advice, folks?  Thanks!

How do you create those VMs?


This works well, but I am capturing all IPs from the specified resource group. If there are additional VMs besides the newly deployed ones, those IPs will also be captured. I just want the IPs of the newly deployed VMs if there happen to be others present.

I suggest you deploy virtual machines with specific tags or set the tags in the network interface like reason:repro.
Now, using the above tags, you can capture the IPs for the particular virtual machine.
$VMs = get-azvm
$ips = @()
foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    [Hashtable]$VMTag = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name  $VM.Name).Tags
    foreach ($h in $VMTag.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (($h.Name -eq "Reason") -and ($h.value -eq "Repro"))
        {
            Write-host "VM with tags Resource:test are" $VM.Name
            $ip=(Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where {$_.Id -eq $VM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id}).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress 
            $ips += $ip 
    } 
    $json = $ips | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray -Compress 
    Write-Output $json    
   }
} 

The above script will get the particular Azure virtual machine deployed with tags and it will capture IP addresses from them.
Output:
VM with tags Resource:test are AG-VM
["192.168.1.9","10.5.0.6","10.5.0.5","172.16.10.4","172.17.11.4","10.0.1.4","10.0.1.5"]
["192.168.1.9","10.5.0.6","10.5.0.5","172.16.10.4","172.17.11.4","10.0.1.4","10.0.1.5"]
["192.168.1.9","10.5.0.6","10.5.0.5","172.16.10.4","172.17.11.4","10.0.1.4","10.0.1.5"]
["192.168.1.9","10.5.0.6","10.5.0.5","172.16.10.4","172.17.11.4","10.0.1.4","10.0.1.5"]
["192.168.1.9","10.5.0.6","10.5.0.5","172.16.10.4","172.17.11.4","10.0.1.4","10.0.1.5"]
["192.168.1.9","10.5.0.6","10.5.0.5","172.16.10.4","172.17.11.4","10.0.1.4","10.0.1.5"]


Reference:
Get Azure VM details by filtering using tags in PowerShell - Stack Overflow by Aatif Akhter
